# on button click give a pop up and open a new tab window and focus on it in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have asp menu item button inside my page.so when i click on that button i need to open a pop up on this current tab and open a new tab and focus on it. When user comeback to the actual tab then will click 'OK' on the pop up before they continue anything.This is what I got so far:

```c#
var menuTable = document.getElementById("<%=ASPTableMenu.ClientID%>");
var menuLinks = menuTable.getElementsByTagName("a");
menuLinks[0].onclick = function () {  
    var winPopup = window.open("z_container.aspx"); 
    if (winPopup) { 
        winPopup.focus();
    } 
    alert('test'); 
}
```

Instead of alert I need to open a pop up with OK button and when user click on OK I need to run some conditions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of alert, you have to use confirm:

```
var menuTable = document.getElementById("<%=ASPTableMenu.ClientID%>");
var menuLinks = menuTable.getElementsByTagName("a");
menuLinks[0].onclick = function () {  
    var winPopup = window.open("z_container.aspx"); 
    if (winPopup) { 
        winPopup.focus();
    } 
    //alert('test'); 
    if (confirm("Your message here")) {
        //OK button clicked; add your code here
    }
}
```